# Is it possible to use stringoverride on ONLY one page?

Tags: 7, ubercart, string-overrides

I want to modify ubercarts "Add to cart" text button but only on ONE page that I've customized. I haven't been able to figure out how to call the button via php so I don't know if that's possible. I figured I could use string override but that would change the text across all pages and for that I can just change the option in ubercart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting you're looking for [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) ... I'm pretty sure its just a [form buttom](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#button) on the page and you can change its `#value`property as-needed with that hook. Its up to you to figure out how to target just that form, on just that page ... I don't think you need stringoverride for this.

You would want to test this out of course :)

Comment: I think this is probably correct. Although my Fapi skills are relatively weak. Can you edit your answer to fit a basic ubercart 'add to cart' form with a bit of an example?

Comment: I dont have ubercart installed anywhere at this time ... setting up a site + ubercart + devel generate (i hope to make dummy content) would take up too much of my time at the moment, apologies.